# How to enable the button on client side

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net button. It is disabled on the page load event. I can enable it by removing the below line:

```
  Private Overloads Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e    As    System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 btnDeleteRecord.Enabled = False
end sub
```

but this will require the release of the whole application to production which is not allowed at this time. Is it possible that I can enable this button on client side. Below is the code for button:

```
<asp:button id="btnDeleteRecord" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete records with the check mark"
                        Text="Delete Records" Enabled="true">
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: using jQuery: `$('[id$=btnDeleteRecord]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include following JavaScript in your aspx page. The method `pageLoad` is `automatically executed` by ASP.Net framework when page loads in the browser.

```
function pageLoad() {
  document.getElementById("<%=btnDeleteRecord.ClientID%>").disabled = false;
}
```